# C# Return List of Databases in Combobox

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, combobox

I have two comboboxes, `comboBoxSelectServer` and `comboBoxSelectDatabase`.

Based on the value selected in `comboBoxSelectServer` when the user clicks on `comboBoxSelectDatabase` they will get the various databases from that server.

However, when running the application I'm not getting any databases returned in `comboBoxSelectDatabase`.

I think its due to the below section of my code, as on debugging its not pulling back anything.

```
comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(command);
```

I've included my code below;

```
if (comboBoxSelectServer.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    string commandTextSERV1 = "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases " +
                              "where name LIKE 'Client_%'";

    string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionStringSERV1;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandTextSERV1, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(command);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is related to `comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(command);`. Here you are adding the SqlCommand object and not any of the returned DataRows to the drop down

Comment: @JayV Yes I've thought the same..but I don't know what to replace it with to pull back the database list. I've tried a few options but nothing works so far..

Comment: Take a google of executereader it comes with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(command);
```

is wrong, it should be:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your following statement. here you are adding command object, instead of reader rows.

```
comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(command);
```

Change it to

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    comboBoxSelectDatabase.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["name"]));
}
```

This should populate the combox with database name.